# Loading relation from multiple directories

Tags: apache-pig, orc

If we have a directory structure like so:

```
/hdfs/foo
/hdfs/foo/foo1
/hdfs/foo/foo2
```

The orc files are in foo1 and foo2.  There could conceivably be any number of subdirectories under foo.  (They are partitioned files).

How can I load all of the files in the subdirectory into a relation?

I've tried:

```
relation = LOAD '/hdfs/foo' USING OrcStorage();
```

This doesn't give me an error, but the relation doesn't have most of the data it should. I really don't understand what this is actually doing.

```
relation = LOAD '/hdfs/foo*' using OrcStorage();
```

That gets me a file not found exception.

```
relation = LOAD '/hdfs/foo/*' using OrcStorage();
```

This also gets me a file not found exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Pig does not allow globbing ([official document](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/basic.html#load)) in load.

we have to do this either using some script or create manual.

you have to do 
relation = LOAD '/hdfs{/foo/file/foo/foo/file...)' using OrcStorage();

Answer (score 0):

I am Suspecting its problem with OrcStorage(), I tried with PigStorage() its working for me..